# Estimate the parameters of beta exponential distribution via L-Moments

Tags: estimation, censoring, l-moments

Estimate 3 parameters of beta exponential distribution in the case of censored type 1 samples via L-moments

Comment: Is this for some subject?

Comment: The answer would probably be a publishable paper in some literatures, e.g. statistical hydrology. By the same token, an answer seems unlikely unless it already has been published.